# How to determine rotation of landscape react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to find a way to determine what the rotation on the landscape view of a 
react-native (android & ios) page is. I know how to detect the change as well as enforce landscape, however, this only forces landscape in a single direction, not both.

How should I go about detecting the rotation of the phone during landscape view?

I can't seem to find a good forum/thread/article showing you how to go about this (in any form).

**EDIT:**
What I mean with the above is how to detect if the phone changes from landscape up to landscape down. ( i.e. turning your phone 180 degrees in either direction).

Comment: Checkout this library [react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation).

Comment: I am now wondering if I am a complete idiot when it comes to googling, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks @Hariks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hariks stated in the comment section, this package helped a lot.
It aided in locking the orientation for most of the screens, while opening the orientation up for a single screen.

Package name: [react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation)